# Manifest v3 - css stylesheet injection not working as supposed to

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I'm creating a extension to apply a stylesheet over chatGPT's site, but no matter how i try it, the code always will apply the .css file that is listed for last on "content_scripts" > "css" (code below)

The extension is supposed to be a theme-selector so i need to be able to apply stylesheets via JS

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Inject MV3 (Content Script)",
  "version": "0.01",
  "description": "-",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://chat.openai.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "css": ["stylesheet.css", "sh_orange.css", "sh_purple.css"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],

  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },

  

  "host_permissions": ["https://chat.openai.com/*"],
  
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["stylesheet.css", "sh_purple.css", "sh_orange.css"],
      "matches": ["https://chat.openai.com/*"]
    }
  ],

  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.url) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
        message: 'urlChanged',
        url: changeInfo.url
      });
    }
  });
```

`contentScript.js`

```
function cores(){
  /* apply the stylesheet */
  var docx = document;
  docx.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"sh_orange.css\" />");

  console.log('[ColorfulGPT] - tema aplicado')
}


// Observe changes to run cores() again if needed
function observeChanges() {
  try {
  
    const targetNode = document.querySelector("#__next");
    if (targetNode) {
      const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
      const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
        for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            cores();
          }
        }
      };
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    }
    console.log('Atualização dinânimca - tema aplicado novamente')
    
  }

  catch(error) {
    console.log('Erro, observeChanges()')
  }

}


//the listener runs cores() again every time the URL changes (necessary when alternating between chats)
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.message === 'urlChanged') {
    cores();
    console.log('[ColorfulGPT] - URL mudou, tema aplicado novamente')
  }
});


cores();
observeChanges();
```

This code will always apply the last item cited in

content_scripts >
"css": ["stylesheet.css", "sh_orange.css", "sh_purple.css"],

in this case, "sh_purple.css". even that i'm applying "sh_orange" in cores()

I expected to be able to apply the .css file using the function cores()

Comment: Remove `content_scripts`, contentScript.js and simply use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts in your background script to register the single css file you want.